# Kernel threads in posix

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, posix, multicore

As far as I understand, the kernel has kernelthreads for each core in a computer and threads from the userspace are scheduled onto these kernel threads (The OS decides which thread from an application gets connected to which kernelthread). Lets say I want to create an application that uses X number of cores on a computer with X cores. If I use regular pthreads, I think it would be possible that the OS decides to have all the threads I created to be scheduled onto a single core. How can I ensure that each each thread is one-on-one with the kernelthreads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should basically trust the kernel you are using (in particular, because there could be another heavy process running; the kernel scheduler will choose tasks to be run during a quantum of time).

Perhaps you are interested in CPU affinity, with non-portable functions like [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html)

Comment: yes, it's just something I was thinking about. If one would like to have as much concurrency as possible and one is running a dedicated system running that specific process, the process could know better how to devide the user level threads among the kernel level threads and I think affinity is the thing that I would then want to set manually

Comment: @Silverrocker Keep in mind it's often not that simple. The system/OS requires some processing too, e.g. there's other daemons running. Or the kernel does network processing, file-system processing etc. If you've pinned one of your threads to a core, and that thread is blocked on e.g. I/O or mutexes/semaphores, that core sits idle while it could have run another thread that somehow was preempted from its core. The OS is in most cases very good at scheduling threads and processes to maximize concurrency.

Comment: thanks! You pointed out some good things there I did not think about.

Answer (score 0):

You're understanding is a bit off.  'kernelthreads' on Linux are basically kernel tasks that are scheduled alongside other processes and threads.  When the kernel's scheduler runs, the scheduling algorithm decides which process/thread, out of the pool of runnable threads, will be scheduled to run next on a given CPU core.  As @Basile Starynkevitch mentioned, you can tell the kernel to pin individual threads from your application to a particular core, which means the operating system's scheduler will only consider running it on that core, along with other threads that are not pinned to a particular core.

In general with multithreading, you don't want your number of threads to be equal to your number of cores, unless you're doing exclusively CPU-bound processing, you want number of threads > number of cores.  When waiting for network or disk IO (i.e. when you're waiting in an accept(2), recv(2), or read(2)) you're thread is not considered runnable.  If N threads > N cores, the operating system may be able to schedule a different thread of yours to do work while waiting for that IO.

Comment: ah, well I was thinking of a case where the process with the threads I'm running would be extreamly CPU bound, maybe some (disk) IO here and there but mostly calculations intense on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is one possible model to implement threading. But such a hierarchical model may not be followed at all by a given POSIX thread implementation. Since somebody already mentioned linux, it dosn't have it, all threads are equal from the point of view of the scheduler, there. They compete for the same resources if you don't specify something extra.

Last time I have seen such a hierarchical model was on a machine with an IRIX OS, long time ago.

So in summary, there is no general rule under POSIX for that, you'd have to look up the documentation of your particular OS or ask a more specific question about it.